# Typescript error with styled-components and AS TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I would like a simple component that I can style and pass a prop the `output` element type with [`as`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop). Using version `5` of `styled-components` and `4` for `TS`

However I get the following TS error

### TS error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; }, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'never' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.  TS2769

    11 |     color: #000;
    12 |   `
  > 13 |   return <Component as={as}>{children}</P>
       |          ^
    14 | }
    15 |
```

The key part of this error is here I believe `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.` However my understanding was that with the `{as = 'p'}` this was the default value for `as`?

### Component

```
import React, { ReactChildren } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export interface TextProps {
  as?: string
  children?: ReactChildren | React.ReactNode | string
}

export const Text = ({ as = 'p', children }: TextProps) => {
  const Component = styled.p`
    color: #000;
  `
  return <Component as={as}>{children}</Component>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is kind of tricky. First of all, to [type correctly](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/35d8501/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L174-L176) `Component` accepting `as` prop you should give it correct typing for that `as-component`. And the second problem is `string` is wide enough to result in `never` type for any other props of `<Component as={as as string}>`. Including `children` prop. So one has to narrow the type of `as` for at least known html tags (as soon as you're allowing to pass only strings there and not custom react components).

So your code may be rewritten as:

```ts
import React, { ReactChildren } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

type KnownTags = keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements

export interface TextProps {
    as?: KnownTags
    children?: ReactChildren | React.ReactNode | string
}

export const Text = ({ as = 'p', children }: TextProps) => {
    const Component = styled.p`
        color: #000;
    `

    return <Component<typeof as> as={as}>{children}</Component>
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I am curious though, how on earth did you discover the `JSX.IntrinsicElements`?

Comment: They are [right there](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ba2bb0f/types/react/index.d.ts#L3060-L3240) in react typings :)

Comment: Haha oh of course! Line 30000000 :P TS is still a rather new deeply baffling thing!!